# Adwords API CampaignCriterionService IpBlock empty IpAddress issue

Tags: google-ads-api

We've experienced issue with CampaignCriterionService while getting IpAddress value for IpBlock criterion.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201502/CampaignCriterionService.IpBlock

It is impossible to get IpAddress value. If you use it in selector - you get error [SelectorError.INVALID_FIELD_NAME @ serviceSelector; trigger:'IpAddress'].

```
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->fields = array('Id', 'CriteriaType', 'IpAddress');
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('CampaignId', 'EQUALS', $campaign->google_id);
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('CriteriaType', 'EQUALS', 'IP_BLOCK');
$selector->paging = new Paging(0, AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);
$page = $campaignCriterionService->get($selector);
```

After hours of struggle we found that you should use "KeywordText" instead of "IpAddress" to get proper value. This is not obvious at all. Hope this hint saves somebody time and efforts. Such things should be definitely in documentation. So, working code looks like following:

```
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->fields = array('Id', 'CriteriaType', 'KeywordText');
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('CampaignId', 'EQUALS', $campaign->google_id);
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('CriteriaType', 'EQUALS', 'IP_BLOCK');
$selector->paging = new Paging(0, AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);
$page = $campaignCriterionService->get($selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use IpAddress as predicate to search by it you should use the same "KeywordText", there is an example:

```
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->fields = array('Id', 'CriteriaType', 'KeywordText');
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('CampaignId', 'EQUALS', $campaign->google_id);
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('CriteriaType', 'EQUALS', 'IP_BLOCK');
$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('KeywordText', 'EQUALS', '192.168.0.1/32');
$selector->paging = new Paging(0, AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);
$page = $campaignCriterionService->get($selector);
print_r($page);
```

Produces output:

```
CampaignCriterionPage Object
(
    [entries] => Array
        (
            [0] => NegativeCampaignCriterion Object
                (
                    [campaignId] => 167195728
                    [isNegative] => 1
                    [criterion] => IpBlock Object
                        (
                            [ipAddress] => 192.168.0.1/32
                            [id] => 23078300211
                            [type] => IP_BLOCK
                            [CriterionType] => IpBlock
                            [_parameterMap:Criterion:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [Criterion.Type] => CriterionType
                                )

                        )

                    [bidModifier] => 
                    [forwardCompatibilityMap] => 
                    [CampaignCriterionType] => NegativeCampaignCriterion
                    [_parameterMap:CampaignCriterion:private] => Array
                        (
                            [CampaignCriterion.Type] => CampaignCriterionType
                        )

                )

        )

    [totalNumEntries] => 1
    [PageType] => CampaignCriterionPage
    [_parameterMap:Page:private] => Array
        (
            [Page.Type] => PageType
        )

)
```